# Static library inspector for windows?

Tags: c++, windows, static

I know there are tools like PE Explorer for inspecting the contents of DLLs on windows (exported symbols, etc).  Is there something similar for static libraries?  I'm linking against a third party library that's generating some linking errors, and I want to double check that the symbols I expect are indeed being provided.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Dumpbin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429)

> The DUMPBIN utility, which is provided with the 32-bit version of Microsoft Visual C++, combines the abilities of the LINK, LIB, and EXEHDR utilities. The combination of these tools features the ability to provide information about the format and symbols provided in executable, library, and DLL files.

Comment: If you want to access the .lib symbols, you can run `dumpbin /headers libname.lib` from inside Developer Command Prompt for VS 20xx.

Answer (score 9):

[dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) comes with Visual Studio and can peek into .lib files. read the documentation to figure out which swich you want to use or just use /all, dump it all to a file and use an editor to search the symbols you're looking for.