# Can you get information out of C++ Lib Files like How you can Get Info out of Jar files?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Are C++ Lib Files binary, or just some sort of container, like a zip file, which contains all of the binary files?

I ask, because I'm curious if I can open a library file (.lib) to get more information about what files are inside of it, similar to how you can open a jar file and look through it in a human readable way.

I ask, because I'm adding some libraries to my lib path and would prefer to know if the lib files contain the classes I'm trying to reference.

Comment: I made the reference to C++ Libs, but the libs may of been made from delphi as well.

Comment: No Library files do not work like packages in Java. They are binary and no container and do not contain files. You can get information out of it like what functions and symbols are exported by using the right tools. Same goes for Delphi.

Comment: There are always `nm` and `c++filt` to tell you which symbols a library defines. But no, there is no real source information inside a C++ library.

Comment: Thanks! Both comments answer what I was looking for. Knowing the tools to see the symbols should give me what I need.

Comment: Dumpbin and Lib (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ykb2k5f(v=vs.71).asp) are the tools for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, a library file is pure binary. So it's impossible to actually 'see' it's contents like a zip file.

If you got hold of some .lib files then it's probable it also came with documentation that explains it's functionality. That would be a good place to check if your classes are present in the library.

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188490/static-library-inspector-for-windows) describes a lib file inspector called dumpbin, might be what you need.

Comment: I would assume there would be some way to "see" what is in it, as programs are able to do just that when they reference the lib files right?

Comment: I think you will find the solution in the following question useful. It describes a lib file inspector called dumpbin. Not sureif it's what you are expecting, but check it out. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188490/static-library-inspector-for-windows)

Comment: Thanks Steve. If you edit your answer to include the extra info, I'll accept your answer. It gives me enough that I can start googling with.

Comment: It should be noticed that dumpbin can handle only COFF libraries, so it isn't useful if you have libraries for C++Builder. Of course it's a different situation if you happen to have COFF libraries and use a utility to convert them to OMF before linking with C++Builder.

Answer (score 1):

A lib file contains the compiled binary of all of the compilation units that are provided by the library. Since you have tagged C++Builder, I assume you have [OMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_Object_Module_Format)-libraries. You can easily get quite a lot of information out of these, for example all function signatures in the library.

C++Builder ships with a tool called [TDump](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility) that prints contents of the library in human-readable form. It's located in the bin-directory under the C++Builder installation directory.

The example below shows you how to use TDump to dump contents of a library from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin\tdump.exe" library.lib > library-dump.txt
```

You can find each object module in the library by searching the output for "THEADR". After the THEADR-line you will have a list of all of the dependency files (basically includes) used when the object was compiled. After the dependencies there are the symbols, including demangled function signatures.

Comment: I don't have TDump or OMF-libraries at hand right now, but I can get you more information on how to interpret the output when I get to work next week, if you need.